# Level advancement and continuation in Temple of Elemental Evil, Scourge of the Slave Lords and Queen of the Spiders

Tags: dnd-3.5e, adnd-1e, conversion

I recently started DMing the Temple of Elemental Evil (ToEE) but in 3.5 edition. My thought is to continue with the Scourge of the Slave Lords (SotSL) and finish with Queen of the Spiders (QotS).

The book module says that:

- ToEE is for 1 to 8 level characters
- SotSL is for 7 - 11 characters
- QofS is for 8 - 14 level characters

Also, in QofS is clearly stated that it should be better (actually, strongly recommended) if the players have finished ToEE and SotSL before playing QotS. So, my question is on how should I handle the level advancement of the players? What level (in average) should the players have on starting the SotSL and QotS? What level the players should have when they finish the QotS? (There are four players in my group.)

Comment: The answer to this depends on how you're converting these 1e adventures to 3.5e - that could skew the level ranges significantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coming out of ToEE they should be 7 or 8.

Coming out of SotSL they should be probably 10 or 11.

That should keep it pretty balanced, from my memory of those modules. Some amount of balance might need to be done as you play- if it's too tough give them some XP or item bumps above recommended, if it's too easy crank the AC's and saves of opponents up a touch.